# How are filters applied in Elastic Search?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

In ES are filters applied before the query?

Say, for example, I am doing a really slow fuzzy search but I am only doing it on a small date range. For an example you can look below (PHP):

```
$res=$client->search(array('index' => 'main', 'body' => array(
    'query' => array(
    'bool' => array(
        'should' => array(
            array('wildcard' => array('title' => '*123*')),
        )
    )
    ),
    'filter' => array(
        'and' => array(
            array('range' => array('created' => array('gte' => date('c',time()-3600), 'lte' => date('c',time()+3600))))
        )
    ),
    'sort' => array()
)));
```

Will the filter be applied before trying that slower search?

Logic would dictate that filters are run and then the query but I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `filtered`-query, then filters will be applied before documents are scored.

This will generally speed things up quite a lot. However, the fuzzy query will still be using the input to build a larger query regardless of the filters.

When you use `filter` right on the `search` object, then the query will first run without respecting the filter, then documents will be filtered out of the *hits* - whereas facets will remain unfiltered.

Therefore, you should almost always use the `filtered`-query, at least when you are not using facets.

Comment: Thanks, Good thing I asked :)